# Why should we use useEffect or componentDidMount in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I do not understand the need to use useEffect for cases where I want to do things, for example, before rendering.
For example, in the code below, I want to fill the data with information, for example, by receiving from an API. Now the difference of the following code:

```
const Product_List = (props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState();

    getData((response)=> setData(response));

    return(
        <FlatList
            data={data}
        />
    )
}
```

With the following code:

```
const Product_List = (props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        getData((response)=> setData(response));
    }, []);

    return(
        <FlatList
            data={data}
        />
    )
}
```

In other words, different of this code:

```
class Product_List extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
        getData((response)=> this.setState({data: response}));
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <FlatList
                data={data}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

With the following code:

```
class Product_List extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        getData((response)=> this.setState({data: response}));
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <FlatList
                data={data}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Function body != class constructor. Instead Function body == Class render method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions which make up Function Components get called *every time* the component is rendered.

`useEffect` puts some code aside so it only runs when one of the dependencies changes.

In your second example, you have a dependency list of `[]` so it only runs when the component is first rendered.

In your first example, you call `getData` **every** time the component is rendered. So it renders, you call `getData`, which calls `setData` which triggers a render, so you call `getData` and you have an infinite loop.

---

Your Class Component code is not equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

When your console.log is outside of useEffect, it runs during the **"render phase"**

> “Render phase”
> Pure and has no side effects. May be paused, aborted or restarted by React.

When you use it inside of useEffect, it runs after the "render phase", or during the **"commit phase"**.

> “Commit phase”
> Can work with DOM, run side effects, schedule updates.

https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

so it would not be wise to do side effects outside useEffect or componentDidMount, as React's behavior isn't always a we expect.