# Will we ever need to use useEffect in React without any dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68926536/why-should-we-use-useeffect-or-componentdidmount-in-react) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760842/why-would-we-use-useeffect-without-a-dependency-array), but I still can't see a perfect use case for useEffect without any dependency array.

Could someone show me an example where we must use the useEffect hook without any dependency array?

For instance,

```
const my_component = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
    });
    return(<X />)
}
```

...can just be replaced by:

```
const my_component = (props) => {
    // ...
    return(<X />)
}
```

...and...

```
const Product_List = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        getData((response)=> setData(response));
    }, []);
    return(<FlatList data={data} />)
}
```

...can just be replaced by:

```
const Product_List = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    if (data===null) getData((response)=> setData(response));
    return(<FlatList data={data} />)
}
```

Comment: By “no dependencies” do you mean an empty array, or undefined?

Comment: @DaveNewton I mean 'undefined'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58579426/438992

Comment: Why is the question closed? It is different from the one suggested.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am asking a different question.

Comment: Recall that functional components are equivalent to the render method of class components. Therefore, useEffect without a dependency array could be a useful way of counting the number of times a component is rendered, which means it can be used to determine if a component is being rendered more times than it should. In a way, it is also equivalent to a useEffect which has a dependency array containing all the states, and props of a component. Such a useEffect can be used to monitor all states of the component without explicitly depending on every one of them.

Comment: How is it different? It answers your question.

Comment: @DaveNewton well...I added an example to my original post. Please take a look.

Comment: `if (data===null) getData((response)=> setData(response));` If your component renders twice before the data can be loaded (eg, because some parent component causes a rerender), then you'll end up fetching twice